# Using double negative

Tags: grammar, polarity-items

Would appreciate if someone helped me understand the following word patterns with examples:

> **なかなか**〜ない
>   **ほとんど**〜ない
>   **ぜんぜん**〜ない

Can any of them be used in a positive context too?

Comment: There are examples in dictionaries, for example these are from Progressive: [なかなか](http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/leaf/je2/56041/m0u/%E3%81%AA%E3%81%8B%E3%81%AA%E3%81%8B/), [ほとんど](http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/leaf/je2/70645/m0u/%E3%81%BB%E3%81%A8%E3%82%93%E3%81%A9/), [ぜんぜん](http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/leaf/je2/42280/m0u/%E3%81%9C%E3%82%93%E3%81%9C%E3%82%93/)

Comment: It looks like you're asking whether these three adverbs are negative polarity items.  I don't see any double negatives.

Comment: I don't see any double negatives either, but apparently - in some languages courses - students are told that `全然` on its own means `not at all` and `ほとんど` `not much/little/hardly any`. Students are then told that Japanese like double negatives, and so should you. I've been to one such course...

Answer (score 2):

「ぜんぜん大丈夫【だいじょうぶ】」 is frequently used to mean "Completely OK" in a positive context.  It may not conform to strict Japanese grammar instruction, but it is widely used by multiple generations of Japanese people.